# 400(bad request) from admin-ajax.php

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy, http-status-code-400

I was scraping https://www.goldentech.com/dealer-locator/ to get data of dealers and I found out that we need to make two request in order to get the data:

1. https://www.goldentech.com/wp-json/store-locator-plus/v2/geocode/642f858f34c3ba85cd1f61b0f591343d/us/501
2. https://www.goldentech.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
   I have figured out that adding two only two headers to the first request would give the expected response

   {
   'Referer': 'https://www.goldentech.com/dealer-locator/',
   'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
   }

for the second request though, i tried everything. I added all the request headers and all the formdata but this url is only giving me 400(bad request) response.
Can someone please help me with this.
this is where i send the request to the first url

```
        for zipcode in zipcodes:
        yield scrapy.Request(f"https://www.goldentech.com/wp-json/store-locator-plus/v2/geocode/642f858f34c3ba85cd1f61b0f591343d/us/{zipcode}", callback=self.get_zipcode_info, headers=self.headers)
        break
```

this is where i send the request to the second url

```
        headers = {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': '1601',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.68338557.1623847312; _hjid=3cc6183f-bc42-42a1-91bc-5bacb5f32cb5; _fbp=fb.1.1623847314112.1626805438; _gid=GA1.2.1518510207.1624188458; _hjTLDTest=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=1',
        'Host': 'www.goldentech.com',
        'Origin': 'https://www.goldentech.com',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Referer': 'https://www.goldentech.com/dealer-locator/',
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    form_data = {
        'action': 'csl_ajax_search',
        'address': '501',
        'formdata': 'addressInput=501&addressInputCity=&addressInputState=&addressInputCountry=&nameSearch=&ignore_radius=0',
        'lat': '39.0178528',
        'lng': '-95.6786165',
        'options[0]': 'href="https://www.storelocatorplus.com/documentation/store-locator-plus/getting-started/shortcodes/#center_map_at">center_map_at</a>="401',
        'options[1]': 'Bridge',
        'options[2]': 'Street,',
        'options[3]': 'Old',
        'options[4]': 'Forge,',
        'options[5]': 'PA',
        'options[6]': '18518"',
        'options[address_autocomplete]': 'none',
        'options[append_to_search]': '',
        'options[city]': '',
        'options[city_selector]': 'hidden',
        'options[country]': '',
        'options[country_selector]': 'hidden',
        'options[cron_import_recurrence]': 'none',
        'options[cron_import_timestamp]': '',
        'options[csv_clear_messages_on_import]': '1',
        'options[csv_duplicates_handling]': 'update',
        'options[csv_file_url]': '',
        'options[csv_skip_geocoding]': '0',
        'options[default_comments]': '0',
        'options[default_page_status]': 'draft',
        'options[default_trackbacks]': '0',
        'options[disable_initial_directory]': '0',
        'options[distance_unit]': 'miles',
        'options[dropdown_style]': 'none',
        'options[google_map_style]': '',
        'options[ignore_radius]': '0',
        'options[immediately_show_locations]': '0',
        'options[initial_radius]': '25',
        'options[installed_version]': '5.5',
        'options[label_directions]': 'Directions',
        'options[label_email]': 'Email',
        'options[label_fax]': 'Fax',
        'options[label_phone]': 'Phone',
        'options[label_website]': 'Website',
        'options[load_data]': '1',
        'options[loading_indicator]': '',
        'options[map_center]': '401 Bridge Street, Old Forge, PA 18518',
        'options[map_center_lat]': '41.3563396',
        'options[map_center_lng]': '-75.7496451',
        'options[map_domain]': 'maps.google.com',
        'options[map_end_icon]': 'https://www.goldentech.com/wp-content/plugins/store-locator-le/images/icons/bulb_red-dot.png',
        'options[map_home_icon]': 'https://www.goldentech.com/wp-content/plugins/store-locator-le/images/icons/blank.png',
        'options[map_region]': 'us',
        'options[map_type]': 'roadmap',
        'options[no_autozoom]': '0',
        'options[no_homeicon_at_start]': '1',
        'options[page_template]': '',
        'options[pages_read_more_text]': '',
        'options[pages_replace_websites]': '1',
        'options[permalink_flush_needed]': '0',
        'options[permalink_starts_with]': 'store-page',
        'options[prepend_permalink_blog]': '1',
        'options[prevent_new_window]': '1',
        'options[selector_behavior]': 'use_both',
        'options[state]': '',
        'options[state_selector]': 'hidden',
        'options[tag_autosubmit]': '0',
        'options[tag_dropdown_first_entry]': 'Search All Dealers',
        'options[tag_label]': '',
        'options[tag_output_processing]': 'as_entered',
        'options[tag_selections]': 'Search Lift Chair Dealers, Search Mobility Dealers, Search Service Dealers',
        'options[tag_selector]': 'dropdown',
        'options[tag_show_any]': '1',
        'options[territory]': '',
        'options[territory_selector]': '',
        'options[title]': 'center_map_at',
        'options[use_nonces]': '0',
        'options[use_same_window]': '1',
        'options[use_sensor]': 'false',
        'options[zoom_level]': '12',
        'options[zoom_tweak]': '0',
        'radius': '75'
    }
    yield scrapy.FormRequest("https://www.goldentech.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", formdata=form_data, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Please post your code if you can.

Comment: i  edit the question... hope it helps in understanding the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Scrapy, but looking at the documentation and seeing that you have specified `formdata`, do you not need to specify a `method` parameter as well? If you leave that out the default is a `GET`. It should be `POST`.

Comment: when you used the function FormRequest, it automatically makes it a post request... the website is not giving ouput on apitester.com either

Comment: If that is not the only form on the page have you tried specifying the `formid` parameter?

Comment: You are sending json data, your Content-Type is set for a form. Use `Content-Type':'application/json'` or use `JsonRequest` method to do the POST.

Comment: although i didn't find the way to do it by including formdata... i added it at the end of the url as string query parameteres and it works